# How to preload an image from local in react native with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm doing a project but i'm stuck when loading a background image.

```
<Image
    source={Images.welcomeBg}
    style={styles.container}
  >
...
</Image>
```

But Image spends 1-2 second to load it
I'm doing follow this [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets.html)
It still doesn't work right now.
Plz help me fix this bug
[image]

Answer (score 8):

you can do this

make new called `cachedAssetAsync.js` (sure you can choose whatever name you like)

```
import { Asset, Font } from 'expo';

export default function cacheAssetsAsync({
  images = [],
  fonts = [],
  videos = [],
}) {
  return Promise.all([
    ...cacheImages(images),
    ...cacheFonts(fonts),
    ...cacheVideos(videos),
  ]);
}

function cacheImages(images) {
  return images.map(image => Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync());
}

function cacheVideos(videos) {
  return videos.map(video => Asset.fromModule(video).downloadAsync());
}

function cacheFonts(fonts) {
  return fonts.map(font => Font.loadAsync(font));
}
```

then in App.js or whatever your root component you use, can do like this

```
  async _loadAssetsAsync() {
    try {
      await cacheAssetsAsync({
        images: [require('./assets/images/exponent-icon.png')],
        fonts: [
          { 'space-mono': require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf') },
          MaterialIcons.font,
        ],
        videos: [require('./assets/videos/ace.mp4')],
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log({ e });
    } finally {
      this.setState({ appIsReady: true });
    }
  }
```

you can do the logic when `appIsReady` is `false` shows loading screen then when `appIsReady` is `true` show the actual screen. And sure you can do this in only one file.

expo doc: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets.html

Comment: Is there any way do this without EXPO?